# Angular - Convert a Observable<number> to a number

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm using ngrx store to record state, my state currently holds my list of accounts and the current page (for paging).

On my list of accounts component i call the store to get the current page and pass that to a service (web api) to get the list of accounts.

```
this.currentPage$ = this.store.select(getCurrentPage);
```

My angular service is expecting a variable (currentPage) but as a type of number, the store select returns an Observable.

```
getListOfCustomer(currentPage: number): Observable<ListDto<CustomerList>> {}
```

My variable `this.currentPage$` is currently a type of `Observable<number>`

How can i convert an 
`Observable<number>` to a `number` to pass it to my service?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

subscribe to get result as number:

```
let currentPageSub :Subscription;
...
this.currentPageSub = this.store.select(getCurrentPage).subscribe(
 (page: number) => {
     this.currentPage$=page;
 }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create an async function and convert the observable to a promise and await it

```
async method(){
    var pageNr = await this.currentPage$.toPromise();
    this.getListOfCustomer(pageNr);
}
```