# How to convert observable data to a number in angular6

Tags: angular

I know this question may have been answered here but it does not address my problem
[Angular - Convert a Observable<number> to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013653/angular-convert-a-observablenumber-to-a-number)

Here, Am trying to pass data as number to my service in angular 6 in order to perform data pagination.
 If I implement something like the line of code, data will get posted to server back end

```
getAll(row: string, rowperpage: string): Observable<any> {
```

Since am working with number that can help me to perform pagination, If implement

```
 getAll(row: number, rowperpage: number): Observable<any> {
```

it will show the error below

**Error in src/app/service/crud.service.ts(47,52): error TS2345: Argument of type'(row: number, rowperpage: number)' is not assignable to parameter of type'(Headers?: HttpHeaders| {header: string |string[];) observe?: "body"; params?**

Please How can i convert an  Observable data to a number to pass it to my service in Angular 6

Here is my **service.ts**

```
//crud_s: Crud[];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(row: number, rowperpage: number): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/list1`, {row: row, rowperpage: rowperpage}).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        this.crud_s = res['data'];
        return this.crud_s;
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

here is my **component.ts**

```
row = 0;
rowperpage = 4;

  getCars(): void {

    this.crudService.getAll(this.row, this.rowperpage).subscribe(
      res => {
  //this.row+=this.rowperpage;
//more code coming

        this.crud_s = res;
      },
      (err) => {
        this.error = err;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. What are these row and rowperpage values supposed to be in the HTTP request? Read the API doc of the get() method. Its second argument is not an abject with a row and a rowperpage properties. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

Comment: Try setting it to params `let params = new HttpParams(); params.set('row', this.row); params.set('rowperpage', this.rowperpage)` and then `return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/list1`, {params})`

Comment: Thanks Suryan, Your solution was helpful. I just only change the observable data to string. so I followed your implementation and got it working as  per this code const params = new HttpParams().set('row', row.toString());   please update your comment so that i can accept it as correct answer to this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error you are quoting is not coming from the line you say it is but it comes from here:

```
 return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/list1`, {row: row, rowperpage: rowperpage})
```

second argument is request specification, not query data. To add query data you have to do it like this:

```
 return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/list1`, {params:{row: row, rowperpage: rowperpage}})
```

or even use HttpParams for this - but still it will be added like above.

Comment: Your implementation also solve my issue by initializing HttpParams  and by converting row and rowperpage to string as per params = new HttpParams().set('row', row.toString());