# Converting Observable data to a number or string in Angular 7

Tags: angular

This question may have been answered, but I still couldn't figure out a solution for my problem: 
[Angular-convert-a-observablenumber-to-a-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013653/angular-convert-a-observablenumber-to-a-number) and [how-to-convert-observable-data-to-a-number-in-angular6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52979309/how-to-convert-observable-data-to-a-number-in-angular6)

I am trying to use the length, next and prev variables. These variables are defined as:

```
let length = this.http.get<Project[]>(this.projectUrl).pipe(map(res => res['count']));
let next = this.http.get<Project[]>(this.projectUrl).pipe(map(res => res['next']));
let prev = this.http.get<Project[]>(this.projectUrl).pipe(map(res=> res['previous']));
```

I have to *typecast* these variables to numbers, that will enable me to write custom pagination function. I tried to typecasting them using *<>* keyword as follows (although this is not a wise approach):

```
private length0 = <unknown> this.http.get<Project[]>(this.projectUrl).pipe(map(res => res['count']));
public length1 = <number> this.length0;

private next0 = <unknown> this.http.get<Project[]>(this.projectUrl).pipe(map(res => res['next']));
public next1 = <string> this.next0;

private prev0 = <unknown> this.http.get<Project[]>(this.projectUrl).pipe(map(res=> res['previous']));
public prev1 = <string> this.prev0;
```

But when I check my console, these are still of type *Observable()*.

Can someone please suggest me how to typecast these variables to numbers ?

Comment: without subscribing you will not get value from observable

Comment: you will always get Observable until you map the value to the variable.
Try to use await, because Observable are async. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013653/angular-convert-a-observablenumber-to-a-number

Comment: @ashish And that's precisely what I couldn't figure out. I will be obliged if you can give me an example, with reference to the variables defined in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `async / await` in this case you will convert the observable to promise

```
let length = await this.http.get<Project[]>(this.projectUrl).pipe(map(res => res['count']))toPromise();
```

> You need to add async in order to use await
>
> ```
> async ngOnInit() {
>   let length = await this.http.get<Project[]>(this.projectUrl).pipe(map(res => res['count']))toPromise();
> }
> ```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-55096330)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. But it's still not clear to me as to how my variables are getting typecasted to number or a string (I have just edited the question!!). _typeof()_ is showing _undefined_. Also, I am using these variables, inside of my service (which is later used by the component.ts file)

Comment: @Virat the type will be infer base of the result or map operation check the demo I have created to demonstrate this 

Comment: Your solution works perfectly from my component.ts file. The thing is I have defined these variables in a service, so using async ngOnInit() isn't possible. Let me know if you can help me figure this out!!